# Flat modules and their relationship with short exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, exact-sequence, flatness

I recently came across the following result on a Wikipedia page:

> Suppose $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is a short exact sequence where $B,\,C$ are flat modules; then $A$ is a flat module.

I wanted to check if this works for arbitrary rings (as opposed to just commutative rings), and whether anyone could point me in the direction of a proof for this result. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the long exact sequence for Tor.

If $B$ and $C$ are, say, flat left $R$-modules, and $M$ is a right $R$-module, then there is an exact sequence
$$\def\Tor{\operatorname{Tor}}\Tor^R_2(M,C)\to\Tor^R_1(M,A)\to\Tor^R_1(M,B)$$ and $\Tor^R_2(M,C)$ and $\Tor^R_1(M,B)$ are zero by hypothesis. It follows that $\Tor^R_1(M,A)=0$ for all right $R$-modules $M$ so that $A$ is flat.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just realised how trivial the question was when I saw your answer. Thank you very much in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Not only this result is true, but even we have that, if $C$ is flat, $A$ is flat if and only if $B$ is flat (as right $R$-modules). You can see a proof, which requires only diagram-chasing, in *Bourbaki, Commutative algebra, ch. 1 ‘Flat modules’*, §4, no. 5, Prop. 5.

Comment: Many thanks! :)

Comment: Or the same argument with $Tor$'s works. Note that in $0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \to 0$ the modules $A$ and $B$ are flat over $\mathbb Z$, bur $C$ is not.

Comment: @evgeny: I think $\mathrm{Tor}$ is too sophisticated a tool for this kind of result.